# How to reset form from higher order component in React?

Tags: reactjs

Iam doing an app in react.js in which iam passing a component to higher order component.Now after form submission in `PersonalInformation` component the form needs to reset which is not happening.It is not happening by refs.

```
class PersonalInformation extends Component{
render(){
return(
  <div>
    <h3>Personal Information</h3>
    <Form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit} ref="form" name="form">
      <fieldset disabled={this.props.disabled}>
        <Input type="text" name="firstName" title="FirstName" value=""/><br/>
        <Input type="text" name="lastName" title="LastName" value=""/><br/>
        <Input type="text" name="fatherName" title="Fathers's Name" value=""/><br/>
        <Input type="text" name="motherName" title="Mother's Name" value=""/><br/>
      </fieldset>
      <button className="btn btn-default">{this.props.buttonName}</button>
    </Form>
  </div>
)
}
}
```

Now the Higher Order component is:

```
var MyHoc = function(AbstractComponent){
return class extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state={
    buttonName:'Edit',
    disabled:true,
    anotherForm:false
  }
  this.handleSubmit=this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  this.newForm=this.newForm.bind(this);
}
handleSubmit(data){
  this.setState({
    buttonName:'Save',
    disabled:false
  })
  if(!this.state.disabled){
    console.log(data);
    this.refs.form.reset();
  }
}
newForm(){
  this.setState({
    anotherForm:true
  })
}
render() {
  return <AbstractComponent {...this.state} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
  newForm={this.newForm} />;
}
}
}

export default MyHoc(PersonalInformation);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access refs from different components. this.refs refers to the ref defined in that particular component.

You can pass a callback method in handleSubmit function and handlesubmit will call that method when it want to reset form. Something like this

```
handleSubmit(data, resetFormCallback){
  this.setState({
    buttonName:'Save',
    disabled:false
  })
  if(!this.state.disabled){
    console.log(data);
    resetFormCallback();
  }
}
```

And then in your child component you pass a callback method while calling handleSubmit

```
class PersonalInformation extends Component{
resetForm = () => {
    this.refs.form.reset();
  }

render(){
return(
  <div>
    <h3>Personal Information</h3>
    <Form onSubmit={(data) => {this.props.handleSubmit(data, this.resetForm)}} ref="form" name="form">
      <fieldset disabled={this.props.disabled}>
        <Input type="text" name="firstName" title="FirstName" value=""/><br/>
        <Input type="text" name="lastName" title="LastName" value=""/><br/>
        <Input type="text" name="fatherName" title="Fathers's Name" value=""/><br/>
        <Input type="text" name="motherName" title="Mother's Name" value=""/><br/>
      </fieldset>
      <button className="btn btn-default">{this.props.buttonName}</button>
    </Form>
  </div>
)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the component in hand.  You are looking for a ref on another component, so that's not going to work.

At this line: `this.refs.form.reset();` instead set some state like `resetForm:true`, which then gets passed down to your child component.  Then you can reset your form from the component it lives in based on the state that gets passed to it via props.